# Errors "OBJC_CLASS_$_MainViewController", referenced from and linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: objective-c

But i am not sure where is the cause of this problem. Can anyone guide me along?? Thanks a lot!

If you need my project for reference, i have upload my project to this link : http://www.mediafire.com/?l5cl3jegdb6x6bk

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi from your code u need to add the `MainViewController.m` file in the build phases compiled files

Click on the xcode project file and press in the `testModel` under the targets
**press --> Build Phases** then

**press --> Compiled Sources** then

**press** on the "**+**" symbol in the bottom bar

then add choose the `MainVIewController.m` file then **press--> Add** then run it will run

I hope this will help to solve your problem

[image: **For your refference**]

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your project you have a reference to a class called `MainViewController` but you've not defined a class of that name.